# Restivus authentication for Meteor methods

Tags: meteor, restivus, meteor-restivus

I'm trying to make my meteor-app for REST services  available. For this I use the package "Restivus" which also works just fine. But once I'd like to run a meteor method `this.userId` is undefined.

```
Api.addRoute('addArticle', {authRequired: true}, {
        post: function () {
            console.log(this.userId); //<-- hwuqtFXf8aKperJ5p
            try {
                Meteor.call("addArticle",this.bodyParams);
            } catch (e) {
                return {code:500,type:e.error,reason:e.reason};
            }
        }
    });
```

the method:

```
new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'addArticle',
....
if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(...); //is thrown
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Meteor methods you get the current userId by doing

```
    Meteor.userId()
```

and not

```
    this.userId
```

So you would need to update your code to

```
    if(!Meteor.userId()){ 
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, '403:Forbidden', 'You shall not pass!')
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this used to work, but it also doesn't work for me, I can see the user and userId in the callback for the route, but not in the meteor method (using `Meteor.userId()`)